# Redirecting to an external URL with anchors in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, anchor

I have a controller in my Rails app that needs to redirect to external URL's and some of them contain anchors. The problem I have is that when I try to redirect to something of the form http://www.some-domain.com/#/path#anchor, I get the error below:

```
ERROR URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): http://www.some-domain.com/#/path#anchor
```

Interestingly enough, redirects to paths of the form http://www.some-domain.com/#/path or http://www.some-domain.com/path#anchor, the redirect works fine. It seems to get confused when there are two "#" characters in the URL.

Is there any way around this? "Fixing" the target URL's to not have two #'s is not an option, as I don't control those.

Comment: Have you tried encoding the second hash as `%23`? Having two hashes in a URI is not valid syntax

Comment: I tried that now and it seemed to work for the two hash case. What's strange is that if there is only one # and I encode it to %23, then the page is not found. How does this work?

Comment: the '#' character indicates the part of the URI called the "fragment". URI's can only have one fragment. I'd assume that by encoding the first '#' the fragment is not being recognized. Here is a doc on URI syntax: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986